# MongoDB password and Lithium framework

Tags: mongodb, passwords, lithium

I came across a scenario in which the MongoDB password was removed from the DB. Then Lithium showed "Connection was reset.. ", instead of lithium error.

I will explain you step by step:

In `Connections.php`

```
Connections::add('default', array(
 'type' => 'MongoDb',
 'host' => 'localhost',
 'database' => 'CWMG'
));
```

Added user in Mongo:

```
C:\>Mongo
> use CWMG
> db.addUser('mongo','awesomeness');
```

Change `Connections.php`

```
Connections::add('default', array(
  'type' => 'MongoDb',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'database' => 'CWMG',
  'login' => 'mongo',
  'password' => 'awesomeness'
));
```

Now remove the user from Mongo

```
db.removeUser('mongo');
```

Change the connection `Connections.php` - now not using password...

```
Connections::add('default', array(
 'type' => 'MongoDb',
 'host' => 'localhost',
 'database' => 'CWMG'
));
```

Now, Connections.php will not work; If you browse the site.. we get an error: "Connection was reset", some times it will redirect to another website.

[image: Lost connection on page]

The only solution, I found, is to add the user back in MongoDB and also the same in Lithium.

So my question is how do I remove a user from MongoDB, once added?

Comment: Do you have a user configured on the admin database in Mongo?

Comment: Do you have access to the server through SSH?

Comment: You need to edit it from /etc/mongod.conf http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

Comment: I use RockMongo to access the Mongo DB with admin

Comment: Yes I have access the server through SSH

Comment: Doesn't seems to have something to do with Lithium.

Comment: Yes, Mehdi, I think it is a problem with Mongo. But Lithium jumps to "Connection is reset" at `https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/data/source/MongoDb.php#L251`, may be this can help in correcting the error shown.

Comment: do you still use auth? If you are removing a user, you should not able to connect to a db without credentials or admin rights.

Comment: I was testing auth. Now I removed the user and I am not able to connect to db without credentials. I have to use the username and password. Alternative. I took backup, removed DB, restarted, added new DB and then restored, worked for me.

Comment: Ok, did you simply tried to restart the mongo daemon?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. It is MongoDB which stores the password association. To remove it I first tried

1. Export Mongo Database
2. Stopped the service
3. Delete Mongo Database
4. Started the service
5. Imported Mongo Database

Checked for the solution.

**Same problem**

So I tried the final and the only solution:

1. Export Mongo Database
2. Stopped the service
3. Deleted the MongoDB folder
4. Installed Mongo again
5. Started the service
6. Imported Mongo Database

Yes! It is now working OK!